# How to display a template in ng-select all the time?

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

In Angular @ng-select, How can we always show a template even if no option is selected?

If an option is selected, I can use ng-multi-label-tmp.
If No option is selected, ng-multi-label-tmp is not rendering. Placeholder is rendering. I need to put a template instead of placeholder (which should be displayed in both situations 1. No option is selected, and 2. Some options are selected).

```
<ng-select
[items]="users$ | async"
[multiple]="true"
bindLabel="name"
bindValue="email"
[(ngModel)]="selectedUsers">
<ng-template ng-multi-label-tmp let-items="items" >
    <div class="ng-value" >
        <span class="ng-value-label">                                                       
           <!--Some icons and labels here. This part dissapears when selectedUsers.length is zero. Even though it is outside the ngFor-->                                                                                    
        </span>                                               
    </div>
    <div class="ng-value" *ngFor="let item of items">
        <span class="ng-value-label"> {{item.name}}</span>
        <span class="ng-value-icon right" (click)="clear(item)">×</span>
    </div>

</ng-template>
```

Comment: Maybe [this example](https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fmulti-select-custom-example.component.ts) help you.

Comment: The link redirects to stackblitz homepage. @kian

Comment: Sorry, i don't know why this happen. you can find it in [this url](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/multiselect) (the last example).

Answer (score 1):

The template will only render if items are present. As far as I know (and after checking the source code of the library), this behavior cannot be changed without modifying the library. I would suggest opening an issue to discuss this feature; it should be easy to implement.

There is a possible workaround, but it's not pretty.
You can add a dummy item to your `selectedUsers` collection to ensure that it is never empty. This item must be identifiable so that you can hide it.

component:

```
selectedUsers = ['hidden'];
```

template:

```
<div class="ng-value" *ngFor="let item of items">
  <ng-container *ngIf="item.email !== 'hidden'">
    <span class="ng-value-label"> {{item.name}}</span>
    <span class="ng-value-icon right" (click)="clear(item)"></span>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

As this dummy item will be removed when all selected items are cleared, you have to disable the *clear all* functionality on `ng-select`: `[clearable]="false"`, or only enable it when more than one item is selected `[clearable]="selectedUsers.length > 1"`. In the later case, you will have to add your dummy item again after clearing.